# Assign static IP for wifi, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, static-ip

I know there are lots of similar questions, and lots of answers. I've tried at least a dozen things and can't get it to work.

I have a new laptop. I want to assign a static IP address over WiFi. Each time I try and then restart the network-manager, it fails to connect. Sometimes I manage to find settings that make it look like it's connected, but isn't.

In case it's of any use, my router is a Virgin Superhub 2.

Results of ifconfig (after restarting the network-manager without attempting a static IP):

```
wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:8a:60:e0:3f:08  
          inet addr:192.168.0.41  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Most recent attempt at /etc/network/interfaces (tho I've tried many others):

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.16
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.255
```

Sorry it's a dup, but none of the answers I've found work.

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Update:

```
$ sudo ifdown wlp2s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp2s0
[sudo] password for harry: 
ifdown: interface wlp2s0 not configured
Configuring interface wlp2s0=wlp2s0 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
wpa_supplicant: wpa-driver nl80211,wext (default)
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlp2s0.pid -i wlp2s0 -D nl80211,wext -C /run/wpa_supplicant
Starting /sbin/wpa_supplicant...
wpa_supplicant: creating sendsigs omission pidfile: /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa_supplicant.wlp2s0.pid
wpa_supplicant: ctrl_interface socket located at /run/wpa_supplicant/wlp2s0
wpa_supplicant: configuring network block -- 0
wpa_supplicant: wpa-ssid "Tolstoy" -- OK
wpa_supplicant: wpa-psk ***** -- OK
wpa_supplicant: enabling network block 0 -- OK
/bin/ip addr add 192.168.0.41/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.0.255       dev wlp2s0 label wlp2s0
/bin/ip link set dev wlp2s0   up
 /bin/ip route add default via 192.168.0.1  dev wlp2s0 onlink 
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant
```

Update - output of ifconfig after disabling, stopping and restarting network:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:39023 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:39023 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:2460682 (2.4 MB)  TX bytes:2460682 (2.4 MB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:8a:60:e0:3f:08  
      inet addr:192.168.0.41  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:24074 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6655 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:6886053 (6.8 MB)  TX bytes:1333918 (1.3 MB)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the IP is not assigned to another device? Have you tried using DHCP but assigning a static IP from the router side?

Comment: I'm sure it's not assigned to another device (I've tried several and checked in the router). I did try doing it from the router side a few times, but the help available for the specific router is less abundant than the help available for Ubuntu, so I switched to trying to do it from the laptop

Comment: Tried reserving your IP on the router yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your help, but I've given up trying to do this from Ubuntu. I tried dozens of things, none of which worked. Eventually, I went back to attempting to reserve the IP on the router, and finally got it to work.

The difficulty with doing it from the Virgin Media metaphorically "Super" Hub is that you have to first disconnect the device before entering its MAC address. From what I've read, this "feature" is unique to that router.

Again, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

No wireless interface will connect without the intended SSID and WPA password.

I doubt that the gateway is x.255. Without trying to set an static IP address, check:

```
route -n
```

I suspect the gateway is eithe x.1 or x.254.

As well, you lack DNS nameservers. I suggest you set up `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.16
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
  wpa-ssid <your_network>
  wpa-psk <your_key>
```

Reboot and check:

```
ifconfig
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Please make certain that the selected IP address, x.16, is outside the DHCP pool allocated in the router.

Next, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

After rebooting the router and the computer, please show us:

```
sudo ifdown wlp2s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp2s0
```

Paste the result at: http://paste.ubuntu.com and give us the link.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think you're right about the gateway being 1, not 255. I tried several variants on your  suggestion, but still no luck

Comment: Let's troubleshoot: `sudo ifdown wlp2s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp2s0` The -v for verbose should produce some clues as to what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I've add the output to the main post

Comment: Looks perfect. Any clues here? `dmesg | grep wlp` As the result may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Thus: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23788794/

Comment: Please add: `rfkill list all` and also: `sudo iw reg get`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23792636/  and http://paste.ubuntu.com/23792654/

Comment: Please see my edit in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Disable network manager. The interfaces in the file get over ridden by the NetworkManager service. Restart networking.service

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager
systemctl stop NetworkManager
systemctl restart networking.service
```

Comment: Can you state how these steps can be carried out ?

Comment: Added commands in answer

Comment: Thanks for this. It's not working for me, tho. "S"ystem should be "s"ystem, I think, and the final line you gave just tells me "Unit network.service not found"

Comment: I edited the answer. Sorry, posted from my phone :)

Comment: Thanks. It runs, but hasn't fixed my problem :(

Comment: Can you add the output of ifconfig in your question after stopping network manager, disabling it, then restarting networking.service please?

Answer (score 0):

Ditd the wifi connection work using DHCP?
I had a similar problem yesterday (set up looks just fine, but not working, e.g. no ping on the wlan or on the internet)

I just got the connection working by setting the router in b/g mode in stead of b/g/n mode.